# MySQL VIEW table

Tags: mysql, view

I am struggling how to create VIEW in MySQL.
I have 5 tables:

```
- users - table with users data
- groups - table with groups data
- group_membership - relational table storing users memberships in groups
- pages - table storing all pages data
- permissions - relational table between pages and groups storing permissions to view page by group.
```

A VIEW that I want to create should show me which pages is user permitted to see according to his memberships in groups.
Example:

```
User ID 1, is in groups 1, 2, 3
group 1 has permission for pages 1,2,3
group 2 has permission for pages 1,2,3,4
group 3 has permission for pages 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

How I can create VIEW that will contain data like

```
user_ID  |  page_ID
--------------------
1        | 1
1        | 2
1        | 3
1        | 4
1        | 5
1        | 6
1        | 7
```

Thanks to everyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `user_permissions` AS
SELECT DISTINCT `gm`.`user_ID`, `p`.`page_ID`
FROM `group_memberships` AS `gm`
INNER JOIN `permissions` AS `p` ON `gm`.`group_ID` = `p`.`group_ID`;
```

However, you'll lose your indexing in the process, and your performance will be sub-par.

Probably better to do this as a stored procedure, or just a plain query, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `p`.`page_ID`
FROM `group_memberships` AS `gm`
INNER JOIN `permissions` AS `p` ON `gm`.`group_ID` = `p`.`group_ID`;
WHERE `gm`.`user_ID` = 123;
```

Comment: you dont actually need to join to users for that, you can take gm.user_id

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `user_permission_view` AS
SELECT g.user_ID, p.page_ID
FROM group_membership g
JOIN permissions p ON p.group_ID = g.group_ID
GROUP BY g.user_ID, p.page_ID
```

Comment: @StevenMoseley without the GROUP BY you'll get multiple rows with the same user/page pair, per the examples from the user, showing that groups can overlap on pages.